# A box has 5 red balls and 4 blue balls(solved)

Tags: combinatorics

Let there be a box with 4 blue balls and 5 red balls. How many ways can i take 3 balls such that there are at least 2 blue balls?

My problem with this exercise and others that are similar to this one is that why is $nCr(4,2)*nCr(7,1)$ different from $nCr(4,2)*nCr(5,1) + nCr(4,3)$ ?

What am i repeating in the first one ?

Comment: Suppose the balls were numbered $b_1,\cdots, b_4, r_1,\cdots, r_5$.  In the first computation you are repeating, say, $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ as $(b_2,b_3,b_1)$. (where the third slot refers to the one chosen as part of $\binom 71$).

Comment: Nevermind im stupid, it's so obvious that i was repeating those outputs...                Thank you anyways ! @lulu